# Instead of using prefixes I want to ask site visitors to upgrade their browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

I'm re-building a site using CSS [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

In checking [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox), I see that flexbox is supported by all modern browsers, except that Safari 8 and IE 10 require vendor prefixes.

In checking Google Analytics, I see that 96% of site visitors in the last 6 months use browsers that fully support flexbox. The remaining 4% use browsers that require prefixes or provide no support.

Since we're talking about 4% of users, and the number will keep getting smaller, (and I like to keep my code as clean and simple as possible), I'm considering not using prefixes, and instead asking users to upgrade their browsers.

> *How can I target older browsers in order to display a message to users asking them to update their browser?*

Here's what I have so far:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <div class="browserupgrade">
        <p>You are using an outdated browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">
           upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    </div>
<![endif]-->
```

This IE conditional comment covers me for IE versions 6, 7, 8 and 9.

These visitors will get an alert with a link to download a current browser. However, [Microsoft discontinued support for conditional comments starting with IE10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx).

Now I need something similar for:

- IE 10
- Safari 7-8
- Opera Mini < 8
- UC Browser for Android
- Android Browser < 4.4

Is there a simple JS/jQuery script to handle this job? Or another lightweight method?

---

### Solution

Thanks for all the answers. Clearly there are many ways to tackle this problem (Modernizr, PHP, jQuery functions, plain Javascript, CSS, browser-update.org, etc.) Many of these methods will do the job completely and effectively.

I went with the simplest one: CSS (credit [@LGSon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34812442/3597276)).

This CSS covers essentially all targeted browsers, except for IE <= 7.

```
.browserupgrade { display: block; }
_:-ms-fullscreen, :root .browserupgrade { display: none; }
:-o-prefocus, .browserupgrade { display: none; }
@supports (display: flex) { .browserupgrade { display: none; }}
```

See the answer for details.

And for those relatively few visitors using IE <= 7, a conditional comment in the HTML:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <div style=" ... inline styles here ...">
        browser upgrade message here
    </div>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: You could also use a build-tool like [autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer) to post-process your CSS before deploying it

Comment: Not a recommended idea. Many users **can't** or aren't permitted to update their broswers. You should have proper fallbacks in place or just accept that you'll lose those users.

Comment: @Paulie_D Can't argue against that, but I also think pushing those who keep us from having lightweight web sites using newer technologies, this might be one way.

Comment: A little back i wrote an answer for checking `flex-wrap` support which could be useful for this question - http://stackoverflow.com/a/26999964/297641

Comment: you want me change my favorite browser, a browser I chose because it enables me to view things do things I cannot do with any other browser just so I can visit your..., page?!!

Comment: @BekimBacaj May I ask which browser is your favorite? ... because this happens on banks webpage's , Google and so on, and has actually more to it than just to see a page, it relates to security issues, functionality not be possible, etc.

Comment: It doesn't matter -but thanks for asking I had to put up with NN4.1 to 4.7 until it was sold out to AOL in times when IE 5 was already a HTML 5 browser. But never asked anyone to drop their surfing board to be able to view my site with all the jingles and bells and things flying in or out with all the transitions, transparency fades, dynamic tables build and population using portable csv and being able to use AJAX years before it got named.  To name but a few...

Comment: @BekimBacaj, You're misinterpreting the strategy. Of course, I don't want you to change your browser just to visit my site. But if you want to visit my site, I'm asking you to update your browser. There's a difference. You're not required to visit my site.

Comment: Put another way, in exchange for greater security, greater functionality, and more efficient and maintainable code, I am willing to risk losing a small percentage of site users.

Comment: But even then, if a pattern emerges of distress or inconvenience among old-browser users, we can always make adjustments, either broadly or case-by-case. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Check the updated answer and use UAparser.js you will be very thorough regarding your browser/version filtering, and additionally it is very light library only 11 kb minified.

Comment: @Michael_B have you heard of https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/ ? I normally just use that as fallback for outdated browsers that support certain features with prefixes.

Comment: @Pangloss, That's a good tool to know about. Thank you. For now, the CSS `@support` solution, with an IE conditional comment, is lightweight and working perfectly for me.

Comment: I'm wondering if there has ever been on soul on this planet that has upgraded their browser because visiting a web page suggested it and after doing so were they still greeted with the msg? Case in point - I have recently installed Opera Mini and UC for testing, supposedly OM supports flexbox - it does not. I would be greeted with a msg to upgrade, and if I did upgrade, I would come back to the same msg. I would leave after going through all of that quite unhappy.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Revised answer after question edit

Here is a CSS only way to achieve that.

As the [CSS `@supports`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) won't work on your targeted (unwanted) browsers: Safari 7-8, IE <= 10, Android Browser < 4.4, UC Browser for Android and Opera Mini < 8, your "browserupgrade" message will be visible on those using this rule.

```
@supports (display: flex) { .browserupgrade { display: none; }}
```

There is a few browsers that still does support the non-prefixed `flex` but doesn't support `@supports`, IE 11<sup>(1)</sup> and Opera Mini 8, but luckily we can address them with a couple of CSS specific rules.

```
/* IE 11 */
_:-ms-fullscreen, :root .browserupgrade { display: none; }

/* Opera Mini 8 */
:-o-prefocus, .browserupgrade { display: none; }
```

---

Here is the complete code to show an upgrade message for your targeted browsers.

CSS

```
.browserupgrade { display: block; }

/* IE 11 */
_:-ms-fullscreen, :root .browserupgrade { display: none; }

/* Opera Mini 8 */
:-o-prefocus, .browserupgrade { display: none; }

/* all modern browsers */
@supports (display: flex) { .browserupgrade { display: none; }}
```

HTML

```
<div class="browserupgrade">
    <p>You are using an outdated browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">
       upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
</div>
```

---

*(1): The IE 11 CSS rule should work on IE Mobile 11 too, though haven't one to test it on.*

---

The CSS `@supports` is also available as an API, [CSS.supports()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/supports). Here is a very well written [article by David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/css-supports).

---

Additionally, if one would like to automatically redirect those browser, here is a small script that does that, after a delay of 10 sec.

```
var el = document.querySelector('.browserupgrade');
if (window.getComputedStyle(el,null).getPropertyValue("display") != 'none') {
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.location = 'http://browsehappy.com/';        
  }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: This really does a good job at covering all my requirements. A clever approach. Clean, simple code. Pure CSS. Excellent! Thank you.

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks, and glad the solution is of such a great value.

Answer (score 14):

## PREMISE

The JavaScript `style` property returns a complete collection of CSS properties that the browser supports for the specified element, which can be tested using the following Snippet:

```js
for(var x in document.body.style)
    console.log(x);
```

This is true whether or not a particular property is explicitly set for the specified element. This can be tested by running the following Snippet in Chrome, for example; the first line will return `false` as Chrome does not yet support the unprefixed `appearance` property while the second line will return `true`.

```js
console.log("appearance" in document.body.style);
console.log("-webkit-appearance" in document.body.style);
```

```css
body{
    appearance:none;
}
```

However, it should be noted that if an unsupported property is set on an element using JavaScript, via the `style` property then checking for the presence of that property will return `true`:

```js
document.body.style.appearance="none";
console.log("appearance" in document.body.style);
```

Therefore we will be using `document.createElement()` to create a temporary element so we can be sure none of the properties we are checking for have been set in this manner. (Thanks to [Gothdo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3853934/gothdo) for this suggestion, which removed the need for any assumptions to be made.)

---

## REQUIREMENTS

Looking at the list of browsers to be targeted:

- Internet Explorer 10 supported flexbox with the `-ms-` prefix.
- Safari 7 & 8 supported flexbox with the `-webkit-` prefix.
- Opera Mini, according to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), has supported flexbox without prefixing since version 5, however I cannot attest to the accuracy of that and am looking for someone to confirm it.
- UC Browser currently (v9.9) supports flexbox with the `-webkit-` prefix.
- Prior to v4.4, Android Browser supported flexbox with the `-webkit-` prefix.

---

## SOLUTION

We can see from that list that all the browsers to be targeted require prefixing of the flexbox properties so we can target them simply by checking for the presence of any of the unprefixed properties in the temporary element's `style` collection. The following Snippet will return `true` when run in any of the above browsers:

```js
console.log(!("flex" in document.createElement("p").style));
```

Armed with this knowledge we can now create a working solution to display the browser upgrade message to the necessary browsers.

```js
if(!("flex" in document.createElement("p").style))
    document.getElementById("browserupgrade").style.display="block";
```

```css
#browserupgrade{
    display:none;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="browserupgrade">
    <p>You are using an outdated browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
</div>
```

---

## NOTES

### Old Syntax

There was a [version of the current flexbox spec that used a slightly different syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120322/) with one of the differences being that the `order` property was named `flex-order`. To the best of my knowledge, the only browser that ever supported that syntax was IE10 which required prefixing so should, therefore, be targeted by the solution above. For the sake of completeness, though, in case there were ever any browsers that supported that syntax without prefixing, you can include an additional check for the presence of the `flex-order` property while also checking that the `order` property isn't present in case there are any browsers that support both versions of the syntax.

```js
var checkstyle=document.createElement("p").style;
if(!("flex" in checkstyle)||("flex-order" in checkstyle&&!("order" in checkstyle)))
    document.getElementById("browserupgrade").style.display="block";
```

```css
#browserupgrade{
    display:none;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="browserupgrade">
    <p>You are using an outdated browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
</div>
```

### Firefox

Firefox added support for unprefixed flexbox properties in version 22 but did not support either the `flex-flow` or `flex-wrap` properties until version 28 so to add v22-27 to our targeting, we should instead check for the presence of one of those properties.

```js
var checkstyle=document.createElement("p").style;
if(!("flex-flow" in checkstyle)||("flex-order" in checkstyle&&!("order" in checkstyle)))
    document.getElementById("browserupgrade").style.display="block";
```

```css
#browserupgrade{
    display:none;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="browserupgrade">
    <p>You are using an outdated browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
</div>
```

### Internet Explorer 11

Despite not requiring prefixing, IE11's support for flexbox is still [extremely buggy](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs) so you might want to consider targeting it as well. There is no way of doing so using any of the flexbox properties, however IE 7-11 (sort of) supported the [`image-rendering` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering) via the non-standard `-ms-interpolation-mode` property, with support later dropped in Edge/v12+ so we can instead check for that. There is no guarantee, though, that this property won't be added back in to a future version of Edge so that should be monitored.

```js
var checkstyle=document.createElement("p").style;
if(!("flex-flow" in checkstyle)||("flex-order" in checkstyle&&!("order" in checkstyle))||"-ms-interpolation-mode" in checkstyle)
    document.getElementById("browserupgrade").style.display="block";
```

```css
#browserupgrade{
    display:none;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="browserupgrade">
    <p>You are using an outdated browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
</div>
```

### Opera Mini

Although [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/) claims full support for flexbox has existed in Opera Mini since version 5 and is widely considered to be an authoritative source for such information, if you still wish to target it, you can do so by checking for the presence of one of the myriad of properties it doesn't support. To keep things concise, though, I'd suggest replacing the `-ms-interpolation-mode` check with a check for [`transform-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style) which is [not supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d) by Opera Mini nor by pre-Edge versions of IE. As with the previous check, this one should be monitored as future versions of Opera Mini which you might not want to target may continue not to support the `transform-style` property.

```js
var checkstyle=document.createElement("p").style;
if(!("flex-flow" in checkstyle)||("flex-order" in checkstyle&&!("order" in checkstyle))||!("transform-style" in checkstyle))
    document.getElementById("browserupgrade").style.display="block";
```

```css
#browserupgrade{
    display:none;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="browserupgrade">
    <p>You are using an outdated browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
</div>
```

---

## UPDATES

**13/05/16:** Added additional checks to target more browsers after question was updated.
**16/05/16:** Added more detailed explanations of the proposed solution based on feedback provided in the comments and to make it worthy of the bounty on offer. Removed checks for [old flexbox spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-flexbox-20090723/) as they were redundant.
**17/05/16:** Added a temporary element to run the checks on, rather than using `document.body`, following Gothdo's suggestion, which led to the removal of suggesting the use of `getElementsByTagName()` for wider browser support.
**23/05/16:** Added notes with suggested checks for Internet Explorer 11 & Opera Mini.

Comment: Great answer, but I suggest using `document.createElement("div")` instead of `document.body` -- this will make sure that the element doesn't have any styles applied.

Comment: Good thinking, @Gothdo, thanks. I'll update my answer momentarily. Do you know what browser support for `createElement()` is like compared to `document.body` and `getElementsByTagName()`?

Comment: [Caniuse says](http://caniuse.com/#search=createelement) that it's "supported in effectively all browsers (since IE6+, Firefox 2+, Chrome 1+ etc)".

Comment: Not supported quite as far back as `getElementsByTagName()` but an acceptable sacrifice as all the browsers the question is looking to target support `createElement()`.

Comment: Great answer which I will use myself along with my own CSS, +1 from me and I decided to share the bounty I got, giving you one at 250

Comment: Thanks, @LGSon, that's incredibly generous of you :)

Answer (score 11):

You can use [modernizr.js](https://modernizr.com) for [feature detection](https://modernizr.com/docs/#what-is-feature-detection).

And then write some JavaScript to re-direct the users to the URL above if the feature isn't found.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes we have a solution for this...**

first of all download a custom build Modernizr from (click here --) [https://modernizr.com/](https://modernizr.com/download?flexbox-flexboxlegacy-flexboxtweener-flexwrap-setclasses&q=flex) 
(for **flexbox property**) then include latest **Jquery** to your page, add some stylesheet and you are done!

(Note: It is not necessary to download a custom build Modernizr, you can use whole complete build directly from [Modernizr CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/modernizr) but as you need to check Flexbox property only; thats why I told you to download a custom build)

**Check this fiddle [flexbox support fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y6tL80oL/2/)**

**Your entire html page (with css, jquery ) will be like this...**

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>BroswerCheck</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #browserupgrade{
            display:none;
            text-align:center;
            background:#F1070B;
            color:#FFFFFF;
            font-family:Segoe, "Segoe UI", Verdana, sans-serif;
            font-size:15px;
            padding:10px;}

        #browserupgrade a{
            color:#FFFFFF;
            background:#000000;
            text-decoration:none;
            padding:5px 15px;
            border-radius:25px;}
    </style>
    <script src="modernizr.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="browserupgrade">
        <p>You are using an outdated browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    </div>

    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (!Modernizr.flexbox) { $("#browserupgrade").show(); }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Your steps will be,

**1. Download custom Modernizr to detect flexbox property**

**2. create a html page with class="no-js" added in html tag**

**3. create a div for displaying a message and hide it**

**4. add jquery and Modernizr to your page**

**5. show a div, when a browser doesn't support flexbox-property**

**(for that purpose use 'Modernizr.flexbox' property as shown in above script)**

or if you dont want to use Jquery then use following script (thanks to @Shaggy) as,

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    if(!Modernizr.flexbox)document.getElementByID("browserupgrade").style.display="‌​block";
});
```

Comment: No need for jQuery here, especially as the question specifies that a lightweight solution is required. I'd suggest using normal JS instead; simply: `if(!Modernizr.flexbox)document.getElementByID("browserupgrade").style.display="block"`.

Comment: Ya... Its not necessary... but I have used .show class of jquery instead of using default javascript properties...
Your solution over jquery is good..

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:**

There are two viable approaches: Modernizr or Feature Queries. Modernizr is the current stable solution, but feature queries `@support`, when fully supported by all browsers, will be the best pure CSS solution for css feature detection.

Currently you need to add some prefixes to target those browsers that do not support feature queries, ie. see LGSon's answer.

**Modernizr approach:**

You can create a flexbox custom Modernizr build pretty easy, as previously recommended: [Modernizr Custom Flexbox Build](https://modernizr.com/download?setclasses&q=flexbox). Reference your custom modernizr javascript file in your website and then add some Html markup and Css classes , something like this:

**NOTE:** Open the snippet in different browsers to check support.

**TESTS:**

No flexbox support: Internet Explorer 10

Flexbox support: Chrome 50

```js
/*! modernizr 3.3.1 (Custom Build) | MIT *
 * https://modernizr.com/download/?-flexbox-setclasses !*/
! function(e, n, t) {
  function r(e, n) {
    return typeof e === n
  }

  function o() {
    var e, n, t, o, s, i, a;
    for (var l in C)
      if (C.hasOwnProperty(l)) {
        if (e = [], n = C[l], n.name && (e.push(n.name.toLowerCase()), n.options && n.options.aliases && n.options.aliases.length))
          for (t = 0; t < n.options.aliases.length; t++) e.push(n.options.aliases[t].toLowerCase());
        for (o = r(n.fn, "function") ? n.fn() : n.fn, s = 0; s < e.length; s++) i = e[s], a = i.split("."), 1 === a.length ? Modernizr[a[0]] = o : (!Modernizr[a[0]] || Modernizr[a[0]] instanceof Boolean || (Modernizr[a[0]] = new Boolean(Modernizr[a[0]])), Modernizr[a[0]][a[1]] = o), g.push((o ? "" : "no-") + a.join("-"))
      }
  }

  function s(e) {
    var n = x.className,
      t = Modernizr._config.classPrefix || "";
    if (_ && (n = n.baseVal), Modernizr._config.enableJSClass) {
      var r = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + t + "no-js(\\s|$)");
      n = n.replace(r, "$1" + t + "js$2")
    }
    Modernizr._config.enableClasses && (n += " " + t + e.join(" " + t), _ ? x.className.baseVal = n : x.className = n)
  }

  function i(e, n) {
    return !!~("" + e).indexOf(n)
  }

  function a() {
    return "function" != typeof n.createElement ? n.createElement(arguments[0]) : _ ? n.createElementNS.call(n, "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", arguments[0]) : n.createElement.apply(n, arguments)
  }

  function l(e) {
    return e.replace(/([a-z])-([a-z])/g, function(e, n, t) {
      return n + t.toUpperCase()
    }).replace(/^-/, "")
  }

  function f(e, n) {
    return function() {
      return e.apply(n, arguments)
    }
  }

  function u(e, n, t) {
    var o;
    for (var s in e)
      if (e[s] in n) return t === !1 ? e[s] : (o = n[e[s]], r(o, "function") ? f(o, t || n) : o);
    return !1
  }

  function d(e) {
    return e.replace(/([A-Z])/g, function(e, n) {
      return "-" + n.toLowerCase()
    }).replace(/^ms-/, "-ms-")
  }

  function p() {
    var e = n.body;
    return e || (e = a(_ ? "svg" : "body"), e.fake = !0), e
  }

  function c(e, t, r, o) {
    var s, i, l, f, u = "modernizr",
      d = a("div"),
      c = p();
    if (parseInt(r, 10))
      for (; r--;) l = a("div"), l.id = o ? o[r] : u + (r + 1), d.appendChild(l);
    return s = a("style"), s.type = "text/css", s.id = "s" + u, (c.fake ? c : d).appendChild(s), c.appendChild(d), s.styleSheet ? s.styleSheet.cssText = e : s.appendChild(n.createTextNode(e)), d.id = u, c.fake && (c.style.background = "", c.style.overflow = "hidden", f = x.style.overflow, x.style.overflow = "hidden", x.appendChild(c)), i = t(d, e), c.fake ? (c.parentNode.removeChild(c), x.style.overflow = f, x.offsetHeight) : d.parentNode.removeChild(d), !!i
  }

  function m(n, r) {
    var o = n.length;
    if ("CSS" in e && "supports" in e.CSS) {
      for (; o--;)
        if (e.CSS.supports(d(n[o]), r)) return !0;
      return !1
    }
    if ("CSSSupportsRule" in e) {
      for (var s = []; o--;) s.push("(" + d(n[o]) + ":" + r + ")");
      return s = s.join(" or "), c("@supports (" + s + ") { #modernizr { position: absolute; } }", function(e) {
        return "absolute" == getComputedStyle(e, null).position
      })
    }
    return t
  }

  function h(e, n, o, s) {
    function f() {
      d && (delete z.style, delete z.modElem)
    }
    if (s = r(s, "undefined") ? !1 : s, !r(o, "undefined")) {
      var u = m(e, o);
      if (!r(u, "undefined")) return u
    }
    for (var d, p, c, h, v, y = ["modernizr", "tspan", "samp"]; !z.style && y.length;) d = !0, z.modElem = a(y.shift()), z.style = z.modElem.style;
    for (c = e.length, p = 0; c > p; p++)
      if (h = e[p], v = z.style[h], i(h, "-") && (h = l(h)), z.style[h] !== t) {
        if (s || r(o, "undefined")) return f(), "pfx" == n ? h : !0;
        try {
          z.style[h] = o
        } catch (g) {}
        if (z.style[h] != v) return f(), "pfx" == n ? h : !0
      }
    return f(), !1
  }

  function v(e, n, t, o, s) {
    var i = e.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + e.slice(1),
      a = (e + " " + b.join(i + " ") + i).split(" ");
    return r(n, "string") || r(n, "undefined") ? h(a, n, o, s) : (a = (e + " " + E.join(i + " ") + i).split(" "), u(a, n, t))
  }

  function y(e, n, r) {
    return v(e, t, t, n, r)
  }
  var g = [],
    C = [],
    w = {
      _version: "3.3.1",
      _config: {
        classPrefix: "",
        enableClasses: !0,
        enableJSClass: !0,
        usePrefixes: !0
      },
      _q: [],
      on: function(e, n) {
        var t = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
          n(t[e])
        }, 0)
      },
      addTest: function(e, n, t) {
        C.push({
          name: e,
          fn: n,
          options: t
        })
      },
      addAsyncTest: function(e) {
        C.push({
          name: null,
          fn: e
        })
      }
    },
    Modernizr = function() {};
  Modernizr.prototype = w, Modernizr = new Modernizr;
  var x = n.documentElement,
    _ = "svg" === x.nodeName.toLowerCase(),
    S = "Moz O ms Webkit",
    b = w._config.usePrefixes ? S.split(" ") : [];
  w._cssomPrefixes = b;
  var E = w._config.usePrefixes ? S.toLowerCase().split(" ") : [];
  w._domPrefixes = E;
  var P = {
    elem: a("modernizr")
  };
  Modernizr._q.push(function() {
    delete P.elem
  });
  var z = {
    style: P.elem.style
  };
  Modernizr._q.unshift(function() {
    delete z.style
  }), w.testAllProps = v, w.testAllProps = y, Modernizr.addTest("flexbox", y("flexBasis", "1px", !0)), o(), s(g), delete w.addTest, delete w.addAsyncTest;
  for (var N = 0; N < Modernizr._q.length; N++) Modernizr._q[N]();
  e.Modernizr = Modernizr
}(window, document);
```

```css
.support-container {
  display: none;
}
.no-flexbox .support-container {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #CE3426;
  padding: 100px;
}
.support-container__update-browser {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.support-container__can-i-use {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #dddddd;
}
.support-container__update-browser a,
.support-container__can-i-use a {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding: 0 3px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="support-container">
  <div id="browserupgrade" class="support-container__update-browser">
    <p>Dear user, you are using an outdated browser. Please
      <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="support-container__can-i-use">
    <p>
      For more browser support info click
      <a href="http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox">here</a>
      .
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**FURTHER EXPLANATION:**

Modernizr checks if the browser supports your custom feature in this case flexbox. If the browser does not support it, Modernizr adds a class to your `<html>` tag. Like this: `<html class="no-flexbox>`. Which you can use at your convenience in your stylesheet.

---

*Additionally*, you can add a function to detect the user's browser and add it to your update browser message for a better UX. Credit: [kennebec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2401861/4305494)

```
navigator.sayswho= (function(){
    var ua= navigator.userAgent, tem,
    M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
    if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
        tem=  /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
        return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '');
    }
    if(M[1]=== 'Chrome'){
        tem= ua.match(/\b(OPR|Edge)\/(\d+)/);
        if(tem!= null) return tem.slice(1).join(' ').replace('OPR', 'Opera');
    }
    M= M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if((tem= ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!= null) M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
    return M.join(' ');
})();
```

Comment: It seems to me that `if (Modernizr.flexbox && Modernizr.flexwrap)` (v3.6.0) is returning `true` if supported via `-webkit-` prefix, whereas i would like it to return `true` *only* if it is fully supported.  For example, `iOS v7, Safari` is returning true but flex is not fully supported and all flex items are stacked as block elements.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, also I suggest to use `modernizr` (download from https://modernizr.com/), but a little bit differently. I take it as a fact that your actual concern is only to detect if the browser supports flexbox or not, and not if it's a particular browser or browser version.

After you install it and load your page, modernizr will put classes into the `<body>` tag. Concerning flexbox it will put either the class `.flexbox` OR the class `.no-flexbox` into the body tag, like `<body class="no-flexbox bgsizecover csscalc">` (and in fact many more classes, unless you download a modernizr custom build only for flexbox). So you can use a simple combined selector for a CSS rule that selects a DIV block into which you write your warning concerning an outdated browser. Example:

Into the HTML, write something like:

```
<div class="browserwarning">Your browser is outdated and cannot display this page properly! Please install an up-to-date browser, which you can get from <a href="http://www.example.com">here</a>.</div>
```

In the CSS stylesheet, add this:

```
.browserwarning {
  display: none;
}
.no-flexbox .browserwarning {
  display: block;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: red;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

This will hide this message first (by the first rule), and then (second rule) only display it in browsers which *cannot* handle flexbox and therefore have the `.no-flexbox` class put into the `body` tag by modernizr when the page is loaded: The combined selector `.no-flexbox .browserwarning` works regardless of *where*  in the body that browser warning is placed - it doesn't have to be a direct child of `body`, but can be anywhere in there.

This works for sure - I've used this in pages I did successfully...

Answer (score 2):

On the front end you could use modernizr library and detect if browser support the modern features you are using.

Another thing to do is to do redirect directly from the back end to a special page. If you are using PHP for the back end you can use get_browser function to detect user agent and then load a normal page or if the browser is one of unsupported browser open a page suggesting users to upgrade.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: Modernizr is already mentioned. But using PHP sounds promising. Good idea. Except the particular function you recommend is discouraged by the highest voted comments on the definition page. The top comment does provide a link to an alternative solution, which may be useful. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. There are many other ways and third party classes that could be used to identify browser from the back end. One of them is https://github.com/cbschuld/Browser.php

Comment: As I mentioned in another comment, user agent sniffing, whether client or server side, requires future releases of browsers that do not currently support (unprefixed) flexbox properties to be monitored and code to be updated if they continue not to support them.

Answer (score 2):

**A more thorough approach.**

You can get the user-agent strings for each browser you are interested and create an array of all the ones you want to exclude.

- [List of User Agent Strings](http://myusers.info/)

Use `navigator.userAgent` to get the visitor's user-agent and check if it is in your **not-supported-browsers** array using jQuery `inArray()`

A simple javascript alert could be thrown for visitors using a browser that is a match.

Here is an example of getting browser related information (example source:[w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_nav_all))

```js
var txt = "";
txt += "<p>User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "</p>";
txt += "<p>Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "</p>";
txt += "<p>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</p>";
txt += "<p>Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "</p>";
txt += "<p>Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "</p>";
txt += "<p>Browser Language: " + navigator.language + "</p>";
txt += "<p>Browser Online: " + navigator.onLine + "</p>";
txt += "<p>Platform: " + navigator.platform + "</p>";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

**UPDATE**

This is a very simple approach, no 3rd party API involved. Simply use [UAparser.js](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js) to filter results. All you need to check from your part is browser name and version. Check the example below

```js
var parser = new UAParser();
 var thisBrowser = parser.getBrowser();
 var thisOS = parser.getOS();
  switch(true) {
    case (thisBrowser.name=="IE" && thisBrowser.version<=10) :
      alert("IE versions older than v11 are not supported");
    break;
    case (thisBrowser.name=="Safari" && (thisBrowser.version>=7 || thisBrowser.version<9)):
      alert("Safari versions 7 and 8 are not supported");
    break;
    case (thisBrowser.name=="Android Webkit Browser" && thisBrowser.version<4.4):
      alert("Default browser of Android OS versions older than v4.4 are not supported.");
    break;
    case (thisBrowser.name=="UC Browser" && thisOS.name=="Android"):
      alert("UC browser versions for Android are not supported.");
    break;
    case (thisBrowser.name=="Opera Mini" && thisBrowser.version<8):
      alert("Default browser of Android OS versions older than v4.4 are not supported.");
    break;
    default:
    alert("Great this is a supported browser");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/UAParser.js/0.7.10/ua-parser.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Or another lightweight method?

If you're serving your page through nginx, there is very useful directive `ancient_browser`.

You need to set a list of browsers you wish to not support:

```
ancient_browser msie 9.0;
```

and then redirect those to special browser-upgrade page:

```
if ($ancient_browser) {
    rewrite ^ /install-chrome.html;
}
```

This way you're not polluting your already existing pages and do not need to load extra css for users who do not need it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also insert prefixes into stylesheet. Check if the browsers style property actually supports the style properties either already present, or dynamically inserted later. Composed it primarily for animations, though could be modified to test for any `css`, style property in the browser. If `props` already present in `stylesheet`, vendor prefixes are inserted into `stylesheet`. If props are later dynamically inserted, vendor prefixes are also inserted, or attached onto those props.

For example, adding prefixes for `animation`, `backface-visibility`, `border-radius`, `box-shadow`, `transform`, `transform-style`, `transition`; also setting prefix at `@keyframes`

```
(function prefix() {
    // var el = $(selector).get(0), i.e.g, $("body").get(0), $("#animated").get(0)
    var prefixes = {"MozAnimation": "-moz-","webkitAnimation": "-webkit-"
                   ,"msAnimation": "-ms-","oAnimation": "-o-"};
    var props = ["animation", "backface-visibility", "border-radius"
                , "box-shadow", "transform", "transform-style", "transition"];
    $.each(prefixes, function(key, val) {
        $("style")
        .attr({"data-prefix": val,"class": String(val).replace(/-/g, "")});
        return !(key in el.style);
    });
    $.each(props, function(index, value) {
        var cssPrefix = $("style").attr("data-prefix");
        if (value in el.style === false) {
            $.fn.pfx = function(prop, pfxprop, q) {
                return $("style").html($("style").text()
                       .replace(new RegExp(prop, "g"), q 
                       + $("style").attr("data-prefix") + pfxprop))
            };
            $("style").pfx("@keyframes", "keyframes", "@")
            .pfx(value, value, "");
        };
    });
}());
```

github https://github.com/guest271314/prefix/blob/master/prefix.1.1.min.js

Answer (score 1):

You can use [UAParser.js](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js). It can give you the browser name, version, os, etc. Here's an [example](http://faisalman.github.io/ua-parser-js/).

There is even a [jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/ua-parser-js/) for it.

```
var parser = new UAParser();
var browser = parser.getBrowser();

// leave only the major version and minor in order to compare
// eg 12.2.4 > 12.2
var secondDot = browser.version.indexOf(".", browser.version.indexOf(".") + 1);
browser.version = parseFloat(browser.version.substr(0, secondDot));

// debugging
$("#browserName").html(browser.name);
$("#browserVersion").html(browser.version);

if (["IE", "Safari", "Opera Mobi", "UCBrowser", "Android Browser"].indexOf(browser.name) != -1) {
    if (browser.name == "IE" && browser.version <= 10) {
        $("#browserupgrade").show();
    }
    if (browser.name == "Safari" && browser.version <= 10) {
        $("#browserupgrade").show();
    }
    if (browser.name == "UCBrowser") {
        $("#browserupgrade").show();
    }
    if (browser.name == "Android Browser" && browser.version <= 4.4) {
        $("#browserupgrade").show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This one line will check for ie10 and return true if ie10 or false otherwise .

```
var ie10 = /MSIE 10/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && /MSIE 10/i.test(navigator.vendor);
```

Did my studies here : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2011/04/15/the-ie10-user-agent-string/

use case

**Option 1**

```
 if(ie10){

    //Do something

    }
```

UPDATE :

Microsoft browsers use @cc_on which will allow you to initiate conditional comments through script .

**Option 2 :**

```
<script>
/*@cc_on

 @if (@_jscript_version == 10){

 document.write("You are using IE10");
}
@*/
</script>
```

FYI . Only EI 10 and below do not support flexbox css . Proof here : http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Hope this helps

Comment: And what about the rest of the browsers that do not support flexbox, as specifically requested in the question?

Comment: the only browsers that do not support flexbox is IE 10 and down . Proof : http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox . IE 11 has partial support and which you can use the same logic above to run the check for ie 10 or 11 .

Comment: None of the mentioned browsers in the question support non prefixed `flexbox`

Answer (score 1):

See : https://browser-update.org/

```
<script> 
var $buoop = {c:2}; 
function $buo_f(){ 
 var e = document.createElement("script"); 
 e.src = "//browser-update.org/update.min.js"; 
 document.body.appendChild(e);
};
try {document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", $buo_f,false)}
catch(e){window.attachEvent("onload", $buo_f)}
</script>
```

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 1):

**You can use the following functions to get the browser name and version :**

```
function get_browser() {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent, tem, M = ua
                .match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i)
                || [];
        if (/trident/i.test(M[1])) {
            tem = /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
            return 'IE ' + (tem[1] || '');
        }
        if (M[1] === 'Chrome') {
            tem = ua.match(/\bOPR\/(\d+)/)
            if (tem != null) {
                return 'Opera ' + tem[1];
            }
        }
        M = M[2] ? [ M[1], M[2] ] : [ navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion,
                '-?' ];
        if ((tem = ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i)) != null) {
            M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
        }
        return M[0];
    }

    function get_browser_version() {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent, tem, M = ua
                .match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i)
                || [];
        if (/trident/i.test(M[1])) {
            tem = /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
            return 'IE ' + (tem[1] || '');
        }
        if (M[1] === 'Chrome') {
            tem = ua.match(/\bOPR\/(\d+)/)
            if (tem != null) {
                return 'Opera ' + tem[1];
            }
        }
        M = M[2] ? [ M[1], M[2] ] : [ navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion,
                '-?' ];
        if ((tem = ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i)) != null) {
            M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
        }
        return M[1];
    }
```

**and you can use the following code to alert the user to update the browser.**

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var browser = get_browser();
        var browser_version = get_browser_version();
        if (browser == "Chrome" && browser_version <= 30) {
            alert("Your browser is below the minimum required version. Please update your browser for this site to function properly");
        }
        if (browser == "Firefox" && browser_version <= 25) {
            alert("Your browser is below the minimum required version. Please update your browser for this site to function properly");
        }
        if (browser == "MSIE" && browser_version <= 8) {
            alert("Your browser is below the minimum required version. Please update your browser for this site to function properly");
        }
    });
```

Comment: The downside to "sniffing" the browser version, though, is that if future releases of UC Browser (currently the only major browser to require prefixing) continue to require prefixing then the code will need to be updated. Also, to be thorough, it requires knowledge of all the minor browsers and their support of flexbox as well.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
navigator.browser = (function() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent, tem,
        M  = ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
    if (/trident/i.test(M[1])) {
        tem =  /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
        return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '');
    }
    if (M[1]=== 'Chrome') {
        tem = ua.match(/\b(OPR|Edge)\/(\d+)/);
        if (tem != null) return tem.slice(1).join(' ').replace('OPR', 'Opera');
    }
    M = M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if ((tem = ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!= null)
        M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
    return M.join(' ');
})();
```

But you are trying to reinvent the wheel, with Modernizr you can do:

```
if (Modernizr.flexbox) {
  // Modern Flexbox supported
}
else {
  // Flexbox syntax not supported
}
```