# Javascript Vendor Prefix

Tags: javascript, vendor-prefix

I would just like to know if there is a vendor prefix requirement for the Javascript code that I have written.Below is the code:

```
var imageZoom = {
     harvester: function(){
         var element = document.getElementById("image_container");
         element.onmouseover = imageZoom.zoomerFunction;
         element.onmouseout = imageZoom.zoomerRevert;
     },

     zoomerFunction: function(){
         var image = document.getElementById("picture");
         image.style.transform = "scale(1.5)";
     },

     zoomerRevert: function(){
         var image = document.getElementById("picture");
         image.style.transform = "scale(1.0)";                                                                                                                  
  }
};
```

Are there vendor prefixes for the image.style.transform? What would they be please? 
Looking forward to your kind support and thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Just to add to @FelixKling comment. The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) can be used to look up any CSS HTML or JavaScript feature you may be interested in. It lists good info on browser support, pollyfills and vendor prefixes.

Comment: @FelixKling: requesting for the format in javascript please. Not the css version of it.

Comment: so for example, would it be refering to say:

Comment: image.style.-webkit-transform = "scale(1.5)"; or did i get the syntax wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
image.style.webkitTransform = "scale(1.5)"
```

Comment: Hey thanks. so if I can clarify, the others would be image.style.msTransform, image.style.mozTransform right?

Comment: @SricharanKrishnan `image.style.MozTransform` with capital `M`, `msTransform` with lowercase `m` see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/37364536/ , https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/

Comment: super and thanks. that little piece of code with the for in loop when executed, gave a list of the properties. this should guide me better now. thanks once again and have a nice day!