# CSS @supports: mixing "not" with "and" or "or"

Tags: css

I would like to serve a certain portion of CSS to browsers that support "display: grid", but are not IE/MS Edge. How do you mix positive and negative @support queries?

Can you write 'and not' or is there a similar notation? Unfortunately the following will not work.

```
@supports not (-ms-ime-align:auto) and (display: grid) {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: possible guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33359157/3597276

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need another set of parentheses surrounding the `not` expression:

```css
@supports (not (-ms-ime-align: auto)) and (display: grid) {
  .example { display: none; }
}
```

```html
<p class=example>You are using IE or Microsoft Edge,
or a different browser that does not support <code>display: grid</code>.
```

This is to make it clear that the `not` is intended to negate the `(-ms-ime-align: auto)` expression and not the entire `@supports` expression, something that was an endless source of confusion in media queries (in which `not` *always* negates an entire media query, as opposed to just one condition when combined with more conditions using `and`).

Comment: Irrelevant question, how in the world did you get 403,000 rep? That surely can't be just from answering questions?

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm: [I've been around.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=106224)

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm He's gotten [quite a bit of rep from asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock?tab=questions), too. But wait until you see Jon Skeet on this site...

Comment: I'm just generally curious how people get THAT high? Is it solely from asking/answering questions? I know this is grossly off topic, sorry for that, just oddly curious and really want to know how this happens.

Comment: Yes, that is the only way to earn reputation (besides suggesting edits before having 2k rep). See [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) for a list of the highest rep users of all time

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm Drop into [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign) and we can talk about off-topic stuff without worry.

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm: Yes, basically. The first couple of pages of my answers are mostly old answers that have accumulated votes in the hundreds over the years (which is why my Yearling badges are relevant). Q&A - it's a hell of a drug.