# Is there is a some css hack for non-supporting flex-box browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with `flexbox` on stock android browser and safari mobile browser. So, is there is a way to catch that flexbox is not support in the browser and use in such case another styles? Like with IE catching `@media screen and (min-width:0\0) and (min-resolution:+72dpi){})` and other?

Comment: Maybe you could use postcss and autoprefix

Comment: Have you tried adding `display` values to see if the browsers you want to support will fall back?

Comment: You may find options here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33359157/3597276