# Creating fallbacks for CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have an interesting dilemma, I have a layout that consists if a container with 9 div's inside of it. Each div has a class of column-1, column-2 or column-3 on it.

```
<div class="grid cols-3">

   <div class="col column-1">
      column-1
   </div>
   <div class="col column-2">
      column-2
   </div>
   <div class="col column-3">
      column-3
   </div>
   <div class="col column-1">
    column-1
  </div>
  <div class="col column-2">
    column-2
  </div>
  <div class="col column-3">
    column-3
  </div>
  <div class="col column-1">
    column-1
  </div>
    <div class="col column-2">
    column-2
  </div>
  <div class="col column-3">
    column-3
  </div>
</div>
```

What I need to do is break these 9 div's into 3 columns of 3 divs with the same class.

I can do this using CSS Grid easily enough, but I need to also create fallbacks for browsers that do not support GRID yet. Which is where I'm struggling.

An example of the markup I am working with is here: https://codepen.io/kirstyburgoine/pen/LmXGZJ

A restriction of this project is that the markup cannot be changed in any way, so this has to be done with CSS (or possibly javascript if thats the only way).

I thought about using flexbox, setting `flex-direction: column` and then setting an order on each class. For example: `.column-1 { order: 1; }`, `.column-2 { order: 2; }`, `.column-3 { order: 3; }`. This brought them all into the correct order but of course theye were all in one column instead of 3 and I can't see a way to break a column into a new column with flex. :(

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You can use `flexbox`, but the issue with browser support will pop up there also.

Comment: Plenty of solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33359157/3597276

Answer (score 0):

you can [@supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40supports) **[codepen](https://codepen.io/arpanpatel/pen/deQXZJ)**

> The @supports CSS at-rule lets you specify declarations that depend on
>   a browser's support for one or more specific CSS features. This is
>   called a feature query. The rule may be placed at the top level of
>   your code or nested inside any other conditional group at-rule.

```
@supports (display: grid) {
  /* your css grid style */
}

 /* your css flex style or fallback css */
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the same grid I did using `flexbox`

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  width: 31%;
  margin: 1%;
}

.column-1 {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

.column-2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.column-3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid cols-3">
  <div class="col column-1">
    column-1
  </div>
  <div class="col column-2">
    column-2
  </div>
  <div class="col column-3">
    column-3
  </div>
  <div class="col column-1">
    column-1
  </div>
  <div class="col column-2">
    column-2
  </div>
  <div class="col column-3">
    column-3
  </div>
  <div class="col column-1">
    column-1
  </div>
    <div class="col column-2">
    column-2
  </div>
  <div class="col column-3">
    column-3
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.grid {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.col {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1%;
}

.column-1 {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

.column-2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.column-3 {
  background-color: blue;
}


.column-1, .column-2, .column-3 {
  width: 31%;
  float: left;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column-1, .column-2, .column-3 {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid cols-3">

  <div class="col column-1">
    column-1
  </div>
  <div class="col column-2">
    column-2
  </div>
  <div class="col column-3">
    column-3
  </div>
  <div class="col column-1">
    column-1
  </div>
  <div class="col column-2">
    column-2
  </div>
  <div class="col column-3">
    column-3
  </div>
  <div class="col column-1">
    column-1
  </div>
    <div class="col column-2">
    column-2
  </div>
  <div class="col column-3">
    column-3
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Well you can use a width for column1, column2 and column3 if you don't want to use grid css and like if you different design for mobile view then you can use media query like a mentioned.