# Using CSS @supports query for CSS env() and CSS variable support

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-variables

We have an issue on mobile that involves using the `vh` unit. Rather than have a gap at the top/bottom of the page that isn't consistent we are hoping to use a couple of the newer features to help us *cut the mustard* for support.

I'm not having much like determining if the `@supports(...){}` media query has a way to work for us here. What I'm hoping to accomplish is...

1. Check support for [css `env()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-env-1/#safe-area-insets) _This would also include a check to the JS version of `CSS.supports` to include JS to update the next fallback...
2. Check support for [CSS variables](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/). Using this feature we'd just recalculate the `vh` based on the windows `innerHeight`(?) and assign it to a CSS variable `--vh`
3. If neither of those two options is available we'd fall back to just much larger than required top and bottom margins.

Is it possible to use the `@supports(...){}` media query for either of these two features?

Comment: `@supports (color: var(--)) { 
   /* has support */
}`

Comment: Also check this post ... shows some nice JS as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33359157/instead-of-using-prefixes-i-want-to-ask-site-visitors-to-upgrade-their-browser

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports#Testing_for_the_support_of_custom_properties