# Flex item not taking height of image child in IE 11

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I'm trying this:

```css
html,body{
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wp {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 300px;
}

.a {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.ai {
    width: 100%;
}

.im {
    outline: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wp">
    <div class="a">

        <div class="ai">
            <img class="im" width="100%" src="https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/2018-10-22-13_27_15-Window.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I get different results in EDGE vs IE 11:

[image: difference_edge_vs_ie11]

In the image the left one is EDGE and the right one is IE11.

I've tried containing the `img` in a `div` as suggested by [Flexbugs](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-5) but I got the same results.

Any ideas how to fix the IE11 version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with IE11, in this case, appears to be that the flex item (`.ai`) takes the intrinsic height of the image (877px) during the rendering process, and then stops responding.

The `width: 100%` command, which scales the image smaller, seems to come after the flex item is sized, but IE11 is already done.

I would use `flex-direction: row` to get around the problem.

Also, to remove that small gap under the image, see this post: [Mystery white space underneath image tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31444891/3597276)

Comment: yeah I guess there is no way I'll be able to actually use the flex column, so what I did was I replaced the image with a div with a background, and then I just used the ratio of the original image to set the correct percentages for the width and height. It only happens with the `img` tag as it has that **intrinsic ratio** as you mentioned. IE11 is indeed dead, and I am thinking of making a special page suggesting to the users that they should upgrade their browsers... it is time for the explorer to perish out of existence.

Comment: You could always crop the actual image to the dimensions you want, and load that into the HTML.

Comment: If you choose the *"upgrade your browser"* path, see my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33359157/3597276

Comment: And instead of making a special page, you could save time by just re-directing them here: http://browsehappy.com/

Answer (score -1):

Flex problems in IE is a common problem, moreover, `display: flex;` is not a widely covered property. Try the following options:

```
.a { flex: 1; }
```

or the parent.

```
.wp { width: 100%; } // or 80%
```

This should resolve the problem.

---

If you want to keep the `.wp` 300px, try the following. Add an extra parent for `.wp` and set it to 300px and set the `.wp` to 100%:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wp-parent">
    <div class="wp">
        <div class="a">
            <div class="ai">
                <img class="im" width="100%" src="/2018-10-22-13_27_15-Window.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wp-parent { 
    width: 300px; 
}

.wp { 
    width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: You usually use `flex` for a flex child, not the flexbox container itself.

Comment: Try to add the `width: 100%` to the `wp` container or the `body` and let me know.

Comment: ok it scales to that, but what if I need the wp to be 300px ?

Comment: I am afraid that's the limitation with flex for IE. You would have to change it into `display: inline-block` or `display: run-in;` Or you could add an extra parent to `.wp` and make that 300px and set for `.wp` 100% width.