# How to detect if CSS code is activated or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

This is a weird question, but I'm using flex on my website and question is: Is it possible to detect via JavaScript or jQuery or something like that if flex is working or not ?? Because flex is not supported on IE 10 and lower and if it would detect that it's being viewed on old web browsers or it's not working, there will be message like: Your web browser is too old, download a new one. Is this even possible ?? Thank you for answers.

Comment: simply detect the browser in this case and you will cover more properties (the common IE detection)

Comment: I woudn't care about old browsers, but maybe check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825157/internet-explorer-11-detection#answer-21825207).

Comment: Yes, use [@supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40supports).

Comment: supports is not supported in IE heh.

Comment: You can do something called feature detection, a popular one for javascript is Modernizer,  https://modernizr.com/

Comment: You're looking for [feature-detection](https://modernizr.com/docs/#what-is-feature-detection).

Comment: @skobaljic, exactly! Browsers that do not support `@supports` will skip right over the style declarations in that block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember css `flex` or `order` property is **animatable**, so you can trigger a class on an element with visibility hidden to turn on `flex` property. Then attach an eventListener for the `transitionend` event, and check if the property is from flex by checking `event.propertyName`, if this event is fired, it means it is supported. Here is a fiddle to illustrate, a class called **active** is turned on a div with `#mock` id and listened for transition:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/yLv39dsm/1/

```
document.getElementById("mock")
.addEventListener("transitionend",function(e){if(e.propertyName.match(/flex/gi)){alert("flex is supported")}});
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("mock").classList.add("active");},1000);
```

Apart from above, this question can help:

[Detecting flex-wrap support in browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761298/detecting-flex-wrap-support-in-browsers?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Also there seems to be an approach that seems to work:

https://gist.github.com/davidhund/b995353fdf9ce387b8a2

And of course, [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) probably has this already.

Comment: It returns this problem in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at scripts.js:2

Comment: Does it say this in the fiddle I linked? Seems like the "mock" id div is not there or the script is in the head, so html is not parsed yet.

Comment: No it doesn't say it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it in the fiddle, do you get the same error there as well?

Comment: No, it works fine in that fiddle.

Comment: Then would you make me your version of your fiddle?So i can see what is going on

Comment: The problem was I had that script in the head, basically before that divs, but now I just put it after that divs and it works just fine. Thank you. Btw. one more question, when I want something to happen when flex is NOT supported I just add `else {}` in that JS script right ?
Just like in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a4fsd0rn/ ?

Comment: yes, replace the alert with whatever you wish to execute

Comment: I mean when it is **NOT** supported. I just add else there. Like in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a4fsd0rn/ ?

Comment: Ah, no, you cannot do that, because other transitions might be triggering it too. Start with a default setting assuming flex is not supported, if the if block triggers than override the default css or whatever behavior you want to execute

Comment: Ohhh... ok. So there is not possibility to somehow other way do that ??

Comment: Ah man, I'm so stupid, we create this mock element with visibility hidden, and we know that the only transition will be from flex, so yes you can add an else block there and execute it too. My head wondered into other situations. Sorry, yes you can do it.After you do the check do not forget to remove the mock element.

Comment: No problem and thank you very much for your help and time. I appreciate that and have a nice rest of the day.